# printing date from db with php multiple format values

Tags: php, html, sql-server

I need read dates from db. I use code:

```
   echo "<td>".(empty($row['date]) ? '' : date_format( $row['date], 'd/m/Y')). "</td>";
```

but i need replace date when value is 1900-01-01 00:00:00 to ''. 
How to add if statement in my query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this just simple condition

```
 $date_text = "";
 if(!empty($row['date']) && $row['date']!='1900-01-01 00:00:00')
 {
    $date_text = date_format( $row['date'], 'd/m/Y'))
 }
 echo "<td>".$date_text."</td>";
```

**UPDATE 2 :**

```
 $date_text = "";
 if(!empty($row['date']) && $row['date']!='' && $row['date']!=0 && $row['date']!='1900-01-01 00:00:00')
 {
    $date_text = date_format( $row['date'], 'd/m/Y'))
 }
 echo "<td>".$date_text."</td>";
```

Comment: I have try all posts here and my script still printing that date (1900-01-01 00:00:00 on format 01/01/1900) But not ''

Answer (score 1):

try `date()`

```
if($row['date'] != '1900-01-01 00:00:00' && !empty($row['date'])) {
  echo "<td>".(empty($row['date']) ? '' : date( 'd/m/Y', strtotime($row['date']))). "</td>";
}
else {
  echo 'date is equal to 1900-01-01 00:00:00 or empty';
}
```

using ternary operator

```
echo "<td>".(($row['date'] != '1900-01-01 00:00:00' && !empty($row['date'])) ? date( 'd/m/Y', strtotime($row['date'])) : ''). "</td>";
```

Comment: this query work fine but i need add more. if date in db = 1900:01:01 00:00:00 then ignore that date

Comment: You have multiple syntax errors in both code examples ( $row['date] )

Comment: @RakeshSharma I have try all posts here and my script still printing that date (1900-01-01 00:00:00 on format 01/01/1900) But not ''

Comment: try to echo your $row['date'] is output '1900-01-01 00:00:00'?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a nested ternary operator like this:

```
$d = empty($row['date']) ? '' : ($row['date'] == '1900-01-01 00:00:00') ? '' : date_format( $row['date'], 'd/m/Y')

echo "<td>". $d . "</td>";
```

Comment: I have try all posts here and my script still printing that date (1900-01-01 00:00:00 on format 01/01/1900) But not ''

Comment: what does var_dump($row['date']); return?